# Jira Java Rest Client: Get IssueLinks from issue

Tags: java, rest, client, jira, parent-child

I'm implementing a tool with the JIRA Javs Rest Client. I perform a query to get all issues which are overdued. After this I would like to check, whether each of them is a child of any other issue.

**Problem**: I cannot find any solution to get the issue links

I tried to get the field "issuelinks" by:

```
issue.getField("issuelinks");
```

and also tried to use the method:

```
getIssueLinks()
```

I also read about an IssueLinkManager but it seems that I cannot import that library as I cannot find the correct maven repository for that.
I also tried to use an adapted JQL query but couldn't find a solution to search for issues without parent issues.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
Issue i = client.getIssueClient().getIssue("XX-1000").claim();
for(IssueLink il : i.getIssueLinks()){
    System.out.println(il);
}
```

Prints:

```
IssueLink{targetIssueKey=XX-1000, targetIssueUri=xxx, issueLinkType=IssueLinkType{name=Duplicate, description=duplicates, direction=OUTBOUND}}
```

What happens when you try it? 
This API works fine, but has no documentation whatsoever. I am using version 4.0.0.